# How to override the default output interpolation of Mustache.js, Hogan.js or Handlebars.js?

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js, mustache, hogan.js

Is there a way change the default output of libraries like Mustache, Hogan and Handlebars?

Here is my context for example:

```
var context = {
  primitive: 1,
  array: [1, 2, 3],
  object: new Object()
}
```

And thats how I would like the result to be when compiling:

```
<div>
  Primitive: {{primitive}}
  Array: {{array}} should output <Array#id> instead of "1,2,3"
  Object: {{object}} should output <Object#id> instead of "[Object object]"
</div>
```

I know that I could override the toString method of those properties, but is there any other way like a callback before the interpolation is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that you can override `Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression` to achieve this inside templates.

Answer (score 0):

with Hogan there migt be, depending what you really want to do with it;
https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js#features

```
var text = "{{^check}}{{#i18n}}No{{/i18n}}{{/check}}";
text +=  "{{#check}}{{#i18n}}Yes{{/i18n}}{{/check}}";
var tree = Hogan.parse(Hogan.scan(text));

// outputs "# check"
console.log(tree[0].tag + " " + tree[0].name);

// outputs "Yes"
console.log(tree[1].nodes[0].nodes[0]);
```

the tags are parsed out, you can manipulate the tree as you see fit, and then compile it when done